# In JSP how to use JSTL forEach in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to use jstl in a javascript but it's not working. On my JSP page, i have a javascript in which i want to populate a var. Here is the code :

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var values = new Array();
  <c:forEach var="support" items="#{myBean.objectList}" >

   values.push(<c:out value="${support.pourcent}"/>);            

  </c:forEach>

 });
</script>
```

I am getting a syntax error with firebug [image]

Comment: In other words, you didn't declare the `<c:xxx>` taglib in top of JSP at all?

Comment: did you forget to Import jstl tag lib
'<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>'

Comment: Is your JSTL in a js file that is used in a JSP, or is it in the JSP itself?

Comment: @Qwerky: `<script>` doesn't work in JS file, it would have yielded a completely different error than the one shown in screenshot. So it's obviously a HTML file (and thus generated by JSP).

Comment: @BalusC I should have spotted that!

Comment: @BalusC in my JSP file, i have include taglibs :   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>

Comment: The problem symptoms suggests otherwise. Are you 100% positive that the URIs are right? You mixed JSTL version 1.1 in `c`/`fn` and JSTL version 1.0 in `fmt`. Which JSTL version are you using? If indeed 1.0, then that totally explains why 1.1 URIs are not recognized. Start at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info to get it right.

Comment: @captain i did not forget the core jstl taglibs

Comment: `items="#{myBean.objectList}` change it to `items="${myBean.objectList}`

Answer (score 0):

I've found, i use tiles. I have different pages: header.jsp ( with all taglibs, style and js file), footer.jsp and content.jsp. To work i would oblide to include tags lib in my content.jsp just for compilation. Thanks